# Cookie value always returns false

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, cookies

I am using cookiebot to comply with GDPR and, so far, cookieBot script doesn't seem to work as intended. So I have to add some additional function to have more control over the content of page such as enable/disable Embebed Youtube videos section as an example.

CookieBot store information related to 4 types on cookies in following format, Not sure if this is in correct JSON format?

> {stamp:'HMzWoJn8V4ZkdRN1DduMHLhS3dKiDDr6VoXCjjeuDMO2w6V+n2CcOg==',necessary:true,preferences:true,statistics:true,marketing:false,ver:1}

and uses `CookieConsent` as name of cookie.

I am trying to read value of these cookies when ever user click on the page using `addEventListener`

```
 document.addEventListener("click", function () {
                console.log("document capture click");
                readCookies();
            }, true);


            function readCookies() {
                console.log("Ready to Read");

                Cookies.get('CookieConsent')

                //Parse the cookie to Object

                cookieval = Cookies.get('CookieConsent');
                console.log(cookieval);

                console.log("Necessary: " + Boolean(cookieval.necessary));
                console.log("Prefrences: " + Boolean(cookieval.preferences));
                console.log("Statistics: " + Boolean(cookieval.statistics));
                console.log("Marketing: " + Boolean(cookieval.marketing));
            }
```

for me issue is that all the values are returned as false, I am using `https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/js-cookie@2/src/js.cookie.min.js` to read cookie values, not sure why cookieval.marketing always return false even if it is true in cookie

**OUTPUT**

```
Ready to Read
{stamp:'HMzWoJn8V4ZkdRN1DduMHLhS3dKiDDr6VoXCjjeuDMO2w6V+n2CcOg==',necessary:true,preferences:true,statistics:true,marketing:false,ver:1}
Necessary: false
Prefrences: false
Statistics: false
Marketing: false
```

Comment: What is the return value of `document.cookie`?

Comment: @str, it return following `CookieConsent={stamp:'HMzWoJn8V4ZkdRN1DduMHLhS3dKiDDr6VoXCjjeuDMO2w6V+n2CcOg==',necessary:true,preferences:true,statistics:true,marketing:false,ver:1}; `

Comment: Did cookiebot write that cookie? If yes, they probably also provide functionality to read it. As it is not JSON, there is no easy and secure way to parse it.

Comment: @str, Cookie is written by cookieBot, but they don't provide any function for user to intereact with cookies for this reason i am looking at custom function

Answer (score -1):

`Cookies.get('CookieConsent');` is going to return a **string**.

If you want to convert the JSON into a JavaScript object, then you have to parse it.

---

NB:

> {stamp:'HMzWoJn8V4ZkdRN1DduMHLhS3dKiDDr6VoXCjjeuDMO2w6V+n2CcOg==',necessary:true,preferences:true,statistics:true,marketing:false,ver:1}

… is not valid JSON.

You will also need to change the code which sets the cookie so it generates valid JSON.

Comment: I am doing that in code ` console.log("Necessary: " + Boolean(cookieval.necessary));` or is this wrong

Comment: @Learning — That code is attempting to read the `necessary` from the object stored in `cookieval` … which is a **string** so it doesn't have a `necessary`. You have to parse the JSON to convert the string of JSON to the object it represents.

Comment: @Quentin It does not seem to be JSON, though.

Comment: Oh yes, I didn't pay enough attention to the quoted code and believed the statement in the question: *CookieBot store information related to 4 types on cookies in following json format*. Answer updated.

Comment: @Quentin, I can change the cookie as it is store by third party CookieBot. so this is not a value jSON format. Is there a way we can atleast read value from this cookie correctly.

Answer (score -2):

You need to do parse the json-like string as follows

```
var cookieStr = Cookies.get('CookieConsent');  //{stamp:'HMzWoJn8V4ZkdRN1DduMHLhS3dKiDDr6VoXCjjeuDMO2w6V+n2CcOg==',necessary:true,preferences:true,statistics:true,marketing:false,ver:1}

cookieStr = cookieStr.substr(1, cookieStr.length - 2);  //Get rid of {} marks

var cookieArr = cookieStr.split(',')    //Separate properties

var cookieObj = {}
cookieArr.forEach(function(item) {
   cookieObj[item.split(':')[0]] = item.split(':')[1];    //Assemble new object
})

console.log("Necessary: " + cookieObj.necessary);
```

Comment: The cookie value is not JSON and cannot be parsed with `JSON.parse`.

Comment: It generates error `SyntaxError: JSON.parse: expected property name or '}'`

Comment: Based on the OPs claims, it is a json string `{stamp:'HMzWoJn8V4ZkdRN1DduMHLhS3dKiDDr6VoXCjjeuDMO2w6V+n2CcOg==',necessary:true,preferences:true,statistics:true,marketing:false,ver:1}`

Comment: Oh yes - the double quotes.

Comment: Parsing such a structure is not that easy. It will break for anything containing `,` or `:` (probably not important for this use case), strings will contain quotes, and it won't work with `false` as `Boolean('false')` equals to `true`.

Comment: Well, it changes data types and string values compared to the original. I would not call that "working".

Comment: You can see a working code and call it anything you like. The process is not effected there. :)

Besides the only data type in OPs input is string. And the answer doesn't change any value. Please get your facts corrected.